# How to construct a template class type that can be substituted for subclasses and then called generically?

Tags: c++, templates

I have 10 Coin types: BTC, ETH, Shift etc. For this I have a superclass "Coin" and subclasses for each of those coins. Then I have a pointer to a "Coin" type, so that I can call each of the subclasses no matter what subtype they are.

Problem is, I only know how to do this in Java and not in C++. I have a hard time searching for the correct terms, because I don't really know what to search for other than "generics". What I want is something like this:

```
// Superclass
class Coin {
public:
    virtual void handleCoin();
};


// Subclass
class BTC: public Coin {
    void handleCoin();
}

BTC::BTC() = default;
BTC::~BTC() = default;

BTC::handleCoin() {
    std::cout << "handling BTC" << std::endl;
}


// Subclass
class ETH: public Coin {
    void handleCoin();
}

ETH::ETH() = default;
ETH::~ETH() = default;

ETH::handleCoin() {
    std::cout << "handling ETH" << std::endl;
}


// Execute
int main() {
    Coin* coin;
    coin = BTC();
    coin.handleCoin();
    coin = ETH();
    coin.handleCoin();
    return 0;
}
```

I want this to print:

```
handling BTC
handling ETH
```

I know I need to work with templates, but I cannot find a specific example of this specific case.

Also, my constructors don't take arguments, so I guess my template declaration would be something like

```
template<>
```

Yet all the examples I see work with

```
template<typename T>
```

and then use type T as function arguments like calling

```
max<float, float>
max<double, double>
```

But that's not what I'm looking for. Is there a way to translate this example above to working C++ code?

Comment: What you are looking for is called polymorphism.

Comment: Or [`static polymorphism`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code posted I don't see a need for templates, virtual methods work without templates. To fix your code in main you need to use pointers/references and also have a virtual destructor.

```
class Coin {
public:
    virtual void handleCoin();
    virtual ~Coin()=default;
};
class BTC: public Coin {
public:
    BTC::BTC() = default;
    //Destructor of a derived class is automatically virtual if the base class's one is.
    void handleCoin();
}

// Subclass
class ETH: public Coin {
    void handleCoin();
    ETH::ETH() = default;
    //Still virtual even if you specify otherwise
    ETH::~ETH() = default;
}
int main() {
    Coin* coin;
    coin = new BTC();//Returns BTC*   <--pointer

    coin->handleCoin();
    delete coin;//Calls Coin::~Coin() -> thus the need for virtual so BTC::~BTC is called instead.
    coin = new ETH();
    coin->handleCoin();
    delete coin;//Same, calls ETH::~ETH()
    return 0;
}
```

Manual memory management is error-prone, from C++11 there's a better approach which should be strongly preferred:

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Coin> coin;//Hides the pointer, but still has pointer-like semantics
    coin = std::make_unique<BTC>();
    coin->handleCoin();
    //Automatically frees old memory
    coin = std::make_unique<BTC>();
    coin->handleCoin();
    //Calls unique ptr's dtor because coin is local variable, which again frees the memory correctly.
    return 0;
}
```